# $(\sin \alpha + \cos\beta)^2 + (\cos\alpha - \sin\beta)^2 - 2\sin(\alpha+\beta) = 2$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to show that the following is true:

$(\sin a + \cos b)^2 + (\cos a - \sin b)^2 - 2\sin(a+b) = 2$

---

$\sin^2a + 2\sin a\cos b + \cos^2b + \cos^2a -2\cos a\sin b + \sin^2b - 2(\sin a\cos b + \cos a\sin b)=$
$\sin^2a + 2\sin a\cos b + \cos^2b + \cos^2a -2\cos a\sin b + \sin^2b - 2\sin a\cos b -2\cos a\sin b=$
$1 + 1 - 4\cos a\sin b = -4\cos a\sin b + 2$

..... I always get:  $-4\cos a\sin b + 2$

I should get:
$-2\cos\alpha\sin\beta + 2\cos\alpha\sin\beta + 2 = 2$

Does anyone get 2 as an answer? I don't know what I'm doing wrong(?!)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i think the answer must be zero.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha Think again. That's a = sign not -

Comment: oh!! I forgot the initial squares of sines and cosines

Comment: Hint: (sin[a]+cos[b])^2 = sin^2[a] + cos^2[b] + 2*sin[a]*cos[b] and sin^2[a]+cos^2[a]=1

Comment: @Santosh Linkha: It should be 2. It seems like an easy problem and it is, but I just can't get that number.

Comment: you didn't note that the change of variables in the second square and got $-4cosαsinβ$

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Your comment looks to me like "[Math Processing Error]  {}{}{}{}{}{}". What's that supposed to mean? Am I missing something?

Comment: The comment was too short, so I just added some invisible spaces that for some reason give your computer trouble. So I will delete. I wrote "I get $2$."

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I'm sorry, but this is how I see your comment: "The comment was too short, so I just added some invisible spaces that for some reason give your computer trouble. So I will delete. I wrote "I get
[Math Processing Error]." Is it my computer's problem? (I've never had it before :(

Comment: Well, all I can say is that on my computer, the comment just above yours comes through with no problem. The only TeX content it has is dollar signs around the 1, and that gave my computer no trouble.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thank you for letting me know! I removed an extention from google chrome, which was apparently preventing me from seeing your *complete* comment.

Comment: By the way, edits to the post have made the answer different. A $+$ has been replaced by a $-$. This should be fixed.

Comment: @André Nicolas The author says in the comments below that it was changed on purpose but it doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "job" is to prove that the left side is equal to the right side, then the minus in the second term needs to be a plus ([answer by rbm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/791916/54514)).

Consider both versions: [Plus](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sinx++%2b+cosy)%5e2+%2b+(cosx+%2b+siny)%5e2+-+2sin(x%2by)+%3d+2)
and [Minus](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sinx++%2b+cosy)%5e2+%2b+(cosx+-+siny)%5e2+-+2sin(x%2by)+%3d+2) and you can see that the plus version is true.

One more possibility is given in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791902/sin-cos2-cos-sin2-2sin-2/792122#comment1639942_791916)

If however the expression is correct, you may want to find the solutions to this problem (which means that you equation is true, but maybe not for all pairs of $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. there are certain restrictions on how you can choose a combination of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that the left side equals to 2):

$$(\sin\alpha + \cos\beta)^2 + (\cos\alpha - \sin\beta)^2 - 2\sin(\alpha + \beta) = 2 \\
\sin^2\alpha + 2\sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos^2\beta + \cos^2\alpha - 2\cos\alpha\sin\beta + \sin^2\beta - 2\sin(\alpha + \beta) = 2 \\
(\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha) + (\sin^2\beta + \cos^2\beta) + 2(\sin\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta) - 2\sin(\alpha + \beta) = 2 \\
1 + 1 + 2\sin(\alpha - \beta) - 2\sin(\alpha + \beta) = 2 \\
2 + 2(\sin(\alpha - \beta) - \sin(\alpha + \beta)) = 2 \\
2(\sin(\alpha - \beta) - \sin(\alpha + \beta)) = 0 \\
\sin(\alpha - \beta) - \sin(\alpha + \beta) = 0 \\
\sin(\alpha - \beta) = \sin(\alpha + \beta) \\
\implies $$
$1° \space \alpha - \beta = \alpha + \beta \implies 2\beta = 0 \implies \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \beta = 0$

since $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin(x)$ :
$2°\space \pi - (\alpha - \beta) = \alpha + \beta \implies \pi = 2\alpha \implies \alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Since

$(\sinα + \cosβ)^2 + (\cosα + \sinβ)^2 - 2\sin(α+β) = $
$(\sinα)^2 + (\cosβ)^2 + 2\sinα\cosβ + (\cosα)^2 + (\sinβ)^2 + 2\cosα\sinβ - 2\sin(α+β)$

and

$(\sinα)^2 + (\cosα)^2 = 1$

then

$((\sinα)^2 + (\cosα)^2) + ((\cosβ)^2 + (\sinβ)^2)  = 2$

and since $2\sin(a+b) = 2\sin(a)\cos(b) + 2\cos(a)\sin(b)$

then

$2\sinα\cosβ  + 2\cosα\sinβ - 2\sin(α+β)  = 0$

so the answer is $2 + 0 = 2$

Comment: (sina + cosb)^2 + (cosa - sinb)^2 - 2sin(a+b) = 2 (I corrected the equation and I appologize for the inaccuracy)

Comment: Are you sure the second term has minus?

Comment: Yep, and that's the reason why I can't get 2 as an answer. Apparently I didn't make any mistake this time.

Comment: I don't think thats correct then if the second term is cos(a) - sin (b)

Comment: @user114141: If you really want a $-$ in the second, you will need $-2\sin(\alpha-\beta)$ at the end.